# Minecraft objects folder empty

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently updated Minecraft to the latest snapshot (for 1.16), and now absolutely no sounds play. Not just music; clicking buttons, breaking blocks, nothing makes a sound.

After scouring the internet for a hopeful solution, I came across one that said to check the 'objects' folder in the 'assets' folder of '.minecraft'. When I looked there, I found it empty.

Now, that post that mentions the objects folder as a possible culprit is from 4 years ago, and this didn't turn out to be the problem of the OP there, so it's a dead-end for me. I hope someone can tell me how to populate that folder properly.

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the game?

Comment: You should try deleting the assets folder entirely. Then the launcher should refill it completely when you start Minecraft next time.

Comment: You, uh, haven't got the sound output of the game disabled, yes? In-game sound settings, PC sound settings, etc.?

Comment: I tried deleting the assets folder. It redownloads still empty. I've tried deleting the entire .minecraft folder, still no dice. As for sound settings, sound is working for everything else on my PC, and when minecraft is running, it appears in the sound mixer, and isn't turned down or anything. Sound in game is also not disabled or anything.
I also just found that I can't change the language either. the whole screen is empty there too.